# Angular 6 and Sharepoint SPFX

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework, angular2, gulp

Just wondering if anyone has any samples or links to instructions for running an angular 6 app on Sharepoint SPFX.

I have followed this example for Angular 5 but it will not work once I upgrade the angular dependencies

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OgEqWtouuU

The error I get on the SPFX workbench when I try to add the webpart is

```
    [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "a884f6f5-e74c-4932-972f-0e1431147413" (AppWebPart).
Original error: ***loadComponent() returned an empty object for component "a884f6f5-e74c-4932-972f-0e1431147413" (AppWebPart).

***INNERERROR:
***loadComponent() returned an empty object for component "a884f6f5-e74c-4932-972f-0e1431147413" (AppWebPart).
***CALLSTACK:
Error
    at SPLoaderError.SPError [as constructor] (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_en-us.js:10183:24)
    at new SPLoaderError (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_en-us.js:4211:28)
    at Function.ErrorBuilder.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_en-us.js:3821:21)
    at Function.ErrorBuilder.buildLoadComponentError (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_en-us.js:3743:21)
    at https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_en-us.js:7952:38
```

The code can be located at this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iF1Low1VYlK0RFYXf1KILZfcEuLnMIjx/view?usp=sharing

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you 
Damien

Comment: Try these links on GitHub: https://github.com/joergkrause/angular-spfx-fabric-boilerplate and https://github.com/JuanCangelosi/SP-Angular-PAC, then, if you find these helpful, you could answer your own question here, and I'm sure the community would appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyKrasheninnikov. The first link is good but cannot seem to load the templates from a file - only inline

Comment: Communicate with the repository owner then. Good luck in your endeavors.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the link mentioned in comments, you can also checkout the [Angular Elements - hello world](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/angularelements-helloworld) webpart which uses Angular 6 and SPFx.

It is based on Angular Elements functionality which packages Angular components as custom elements quite similar to web components.

This is a hello world sample, but it also demonstrates couple other webparts as well which can make REST calls to SharePoint, Microsoft Graph, bootstrapping Angular Elements inside SPFx webparts etc.

Comment: Thank you @gautamsheth. Are Angular Elements fully supported in a production environment? I updated the sample to use a html file instead of an inline template. Is this a limitation or something I need to look at with the gulp file?

Comment: Not sure about production ready, but looks like it needs some polyfill support for Edge. You might need to look into gulp to use html or you check [this](https://winsmarts.com/getting-started-with-angular-elements-1bbdf2e748a6) link or [this](https://techenthusiast.in/2018/06/25/integrate-angular-elements-with-sharepoint-framework/) link, maybe it can give you some heads up.